# The pullback along absolute Frobenius is $p$-linear and injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the map $f^*_X: H^0(X,\Omega_{X}) \to H^0(X,\Omega_{X}^{p})$ on a smooth projective curve $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$, with $\Omega_{X}$ the module of differentials and $f_X$ the absolute Frobenius of $X$.

> Prove that $f^*_X$ is $p$-linear and injective?

---

$p$-linearity follows from  the definition of the pullback of a section since $\forall s\in H^0(X,\Omega_{X}), f^*_X(gs):= (gs)^p=g^p f^*_X(s)$.

For injectivity, we have $f^*_X(s)=0 \Rightarrow s^p=0$. I need thus to make sure that the sheaf of differentials have no nilpotent sections.  Is it true? I couldn't find any reference on this.